# jdbc to hive connection refused

Tags: java, sql, hadoop, jdbc, hive

I am trying to connect to hive via jdbc. Below is the code i am using:

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.Connection;

public class HiveToJava {
    private static String driverName = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        try {
            Class.forName(driverName);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:hive://localhost:10000/default", "", "");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        String tableName = "processed";
        ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery("describe " + tableName);
        while (res.next()) {
            System.out.println(res.getString(1) + "\t" + res.getString(2));
        }

    }
}
```

When I run this class as a Java application, I get this msg :

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Could not establish
>   connection to localhost:10000/default: java.net.ConnectException:
>   Connection refused

Please help.

Comment: are sure creditionals are not required

Comment: It looks like either the port is wrong, the server isn't running, credentials are wrong, or you have a firewall issue.

Comment: I solved the above problem. The issue was that i did not start the hiveserver. My bad.

Answer (score -1):

Try the below code you may get the output....

```
package com.services.connections;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class ConnectHive
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException,ClassNotFoundException
 {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String connectionURL = "jdbc:hive://localhost:9999/javatesting";
    String drivername = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";
    String username = "";
    String password = "";
    try {
        Class.forName(drivername);
            } 
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
          {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
          }
          try {
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, username, password);
            if(con != null) 
            {
            System.out.println("Connected");
                }
            else
                {
            System.out.println("Not Connected");
            }
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement(); 
            // select * query
            String sql;
            ResultSet res;
            sql = "select * from javatesting.testdata";
            System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
                res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            while (res.next())
            {
                  System.out.println(String.valueOf(res.getString(1)) + "\t" + res.getString(2));
            }
              }
          catch(SQLException se) 
          {
            se.printStackTrace();
          }
  }

}
```